# How to coverage dynamic python code (compiled with `compile()`)

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

Is there a way to do dynamic coverage ? for example suppose this pytest code :

```
src = '''
def virtual_func(a):
  if a < 5 :
    return 'LESS THAN FIVE'
  else :
    return 'MORE THAN FIVE'
'''
    
obj = compile(src, 'my_file_name.py', 'exec') 



def test_dyncov():
  g = dict()
  exec(obj, g, g)
  assert 'LESS THAN FIVE' == g['virtual_func'](3)
```

How could I get a coverage report for *my_file_name.py* ?

NOTE : This is a minimal test case example. In real life, it would be used to coverage a template engine's generated python template. By the way, in the real life code, the template is loaded almost like a module, and it gets a virtual module name and a virtual file name (but everything stays in memory). If possible, I would like to know how to get the report using the virtual file name ('my_file_name.py' in thie example)

Answer (score 0):

Coverage.py supports plugins which can do this: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/api_plugin.html

Not many have been written, so it might be a bit uphill to write one, but it can be done.  Is this your own template engine, or a public one?

Comment: my own, which is public : https://github.com/hl037/skbs

Comment: I've found that entries are added to the .coverage for everything in the exec. However, the file name become prefixed with the current directory. Thus, I suspect that it is not reported because Coverage.py can't retrieve the sources, which may indeed be fixed using a plugin

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of the file names you are seeing?